# Testing a Web and Mobile Application

Tags: java, selenium, appium

I have a odd situation where I am writing a TestNG test that us written using Selenium.  We have a new requirement now that is testing the same application on a cell phone that is a native app.  I started playing around with Appium to test the native side with Selenium on the web side but I was struggling on how to tie this all together.  So, I thought I was just testing two apps but it is actually one application flow that **transcends both the native app and web app** which is the monkey wrench.

Our tests take a long time to run as it seems to wait on each application.  The 2nd problem is that we are not Java developers per-se (a small QA team).

So, my LONG winded question here is should we be using Selenium / Appium in this situation and is there any recommendations for handling multiple devices?

Thanks,
N

Comment: This really should go on the SQA site because it's not a specific programming question so will likely get closed.

Comment: Are you implying that the end user should have both mobile and web browser to use the application.

Comment: The idea is like a work flow.  They are submitting something via their mobile application (native).  After it is submitted they can check the status via a website.  We were tasked with doing this using a desktop browser and a mobile device.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We used xframium at my last job before I left.  Check out the keyword for devices (http://xframium.org/keyword.html#kw-adddevice).  It is all open source software you can get what you need although the xml stuff was pretty cool